# function includes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the same value on string after split

If I have the numbers (as a string): `1,6,18,2` and I use `.includes` I get an output which looks like this: `1,2,6,8,18`

How can I get same with that string -> `1,2,6,18`

This is my code in js :

```
trHTML = '';    
total = 20; 
var antrian = $('#antrian').val(); // 1,6,18,2

for(i = 1; i <= total; i++){
   if(antrian.includes(i)){
     trHTML += <button style="background-color: gray;"> '+ i +'</button>';
   } else {
     trHTML += <button style="background-color: red;"> '+ i +'</button>';  
   }
}
```

From that code I got button output button with number, if I `consol.log(trHTML)` the output is `1,2,6,18` but output in HTML is gray button `1,2,6,8,18` and others is red button

How can I got grey button with number `1,2,6,18` or same with `console.log(trHTML)` ?

Can someone help me or give me an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why `8` is included in `1,6,18,2` is that there is an `8` in the string. One option is make `antrian` an array using `split()`

```
var trHTML = '';    //Add var
var total = 20;     //Add var
var antrian = $('#antrian').val().split(","); //Add split() - this will return to [1,6,18,2]

for(var i = 1; i <= total; i++){ //Add var on i
   if(antrian.includes(i.toString())){
     trHTML += '<button style="background-color: gray;"> '+ i +'</button>';
   } else {
     trHTML += '<button style="background-color: red;"> '+ i +'</button>';  
   }
}
```